# Determining whether either of a pair of strings ends the other string

Tags: java, regex, string, if-statement, char

I'm working on some codingbat tasks for class; however, I'm a bit more experienced than the rest of the class, so I've been trying to challenge myself by golfing my code down, not using loops, etc.

Currently, I'm working on [the endOther](https://codingbat.com/prob/p126880) challenge. The text of the challenge is as follows:

Given two strings, return true if either of the strings appears at the very end of the other string, ignoring upper/lower case differences (in other words, the computation should not be "case sensitive").

Currently, my code is as follows:

```java
public boolean endOther(String a, String b) {
  a = a.toLowerCase(); //convert string
  b = b.toLowerCase(); //convert string
  if((a.indexOf(b) == a.length() - b.length()) || (b.indexOf(a) == b.length() - a.length())) 

//if the starting location of the second string within the first is the same
//as the difference in length between the two strings, the second string ends
//the first string

  return true;
  else
  return false;
}
```

Which, for the most part, works. However, given a specific case (such as the following inputs: Hiabc, abcd), the code will fail. If one string is not found in the other, then `foo.indexOf(bar)` will return `-1`. This is normally okay, and to be expected; however, if two string have adjacent length values (e.g. 4 and 5) and the shorter string does not end the other string, the statement will still return `-1`. The five-character string cannot be found in the four-character string (return value `-1`), and when its length is subtracted from the four-character string, it will again return `-1`, compare the two values, and finally return true.

I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to except this statement. There are bulky answers - a try/catch statement, wherein a pair of `-1` being compared will still return false, for example - but I don't like how bulky these are, when I'm trying to figure out how to work through the logic of these assignments as efficiently as possible.

Any input would be appreciated. I haven't been able to come up with much besides for bulky if statements and try/catch blocks that except the exact instance I mentioned, which appears to be the only issue with my code. Thanks all in advance.

Comment: You could _separately_ find `final int bInA = a.indexOf(b);` and then test `if (bInA != -1 && bInA == a.length() - b.length() ...)` to check both things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex and `"$"` sign, which means end of the whole expression:

```
a.matches(".*" + b + "$") || b.matches(".*" + a + "$")
```

It's because `String#indexOf` return the first index, that's why:

```
String a = "abcdabcd";
String c = "abcd";
System.out.println(a.indexOf(c) == 0);
```

prints:

> true

And your algorithm won't work.

This snippet describes it:

```
String a = "abcdabcd";
String b = "abc";
String c = "abcd";
System.out.println(a.matches(".*" + b + "$")); // false - doesn't match end of a, although clearly is part of it
System.out.println(a.matches(".*" + c + "$")); // true - that's what we want
System.out.println(a.indexOf(c) == 0); // true - returns lowest index
```

P.S.: It's case sensitive, I'm assuming you're using part of your snippet when needed:

a = a.toLowerCase(); //convert string
  b = b.toLowerCase(); //convert string

Comment: I'm accepting this answer; the usage of regex is exactly what I was going for. I understood how to work out the problem, but I was going for something as non-verbose as possible. 

Regular expressions are definitely one of my weak points, I should have been able to figure that out. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Besides using `regex`, you also just use `lastIndexOf()` to rework your algorithm to ensure the final index of the passed `String` is the one used:

```
public static boolean endOther(String a, String b) {
      a = a.toLowerCase();
      b = b.toLowerCase();
      return (a.lastIndexOf(b) == a.length() - b.length()) || 
             (b.lastIndexOf(a) == b.length() - a.length()); 
}
```

Additionally you can just return the `boolean` directly instead of using an `if` or `else`, to cut down on the code some.

**Example Runs:**

```
System.out.println(endOther("xyzxyz", "xyz")); //true
System.out.println(endOther("xyzxyze", "xyz")); //false
```

**EDIT:**
Missed the case failing for the OP.  I made some alterations on the algorithm that checks if the `substring` of the `lastIndex` is equal to the other `String`, which seems to work for all cases.  This also makes it so I need to check if the `index > 0` because I cannot `substring` a negative number.

```
public static boolean endOther(String a, String b) {
      a = a.toLowerCase();
      b = b.toLowerCase();
      int bInA = a.lastIndexOf(b);
      int aInB = b.lastIndexOf(a);
      if (bInA >= 0) {
          return a.substring(bInA).equals(b);
      }
      if (aInB >= 0){
          return b.substring(aInB).equals(a); 
      }
      return false;
}
```

**Note:**  Remember `substring` with only a single parameter will `substring` that index all the way to the end of the `String`, which is why this algorithm works.

Comment: Usage of lastIndexOf cuts down on some errors, but not the one specifically referred to in the OP. Good to know that it exists, though; I had missed that.

Comment: @Eli K My mistake, missed what was not working for you.  I added an altered version that uses `lastIndex` with `substring` instead of subtracting the lengths.  Seems to be working in the case that was not working for you before.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused why everyone's creating such complicated code. Perhaps I'm out of the loop here.

```java
public boolean endOther(String a, String b) {
  String first = a.toLowerCase();
  String second = b.toLowerCase();
  return first.endsWith(second) || second.endsWith(first);
}
```

Works perfectly fine and should be rather self explanatory. You can optimise this code by making light checks that cover some cases.
In addition to this you could write your own `endsWith` function, which compares chars case insensitive, avoiding the two allocations.

Answer (score 0):

1. startsWith/EndsWith
2. boolean expression usage

So

```
a = a.toLowerCase();
b = b.toLowerCase();
return a.length() < b.length() ? b.startsWith(a) || b.endsWith(a)
                               : a.startsWith(b) || a.endsWith(b);
```

Of course one could swap `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'd do:

```java
public static boolean endOther(String a, String b) {
    for (int aIndex = a.length(), bIndex = b.length(); aIndex >= 0 && bIndex >= 0;) {
        aIndex--;
        bIndex--;
        if (Character.toLowerCase(a.charAt(aIndex)) != Character.toLowerCase(b.charAt(bIndex))) {
            return false;
        } else if (aIndex == 0 || bIndex == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is why:

- it returns false as soon as it detects it
- it doesn't need to convert both string to lowercase upfront

**WARNING:** this example:

- is not `null` safe. You didn't specify what the result should be if one (or both) of the strings is `null`
- does not work with empty strings. You didn't specify what the result should be if one (or both) of the strings is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you break down the problem, you only need to compare the characters from the end of the string one by one until one doesn't match or the shortest string length is met rather than searching for the substring.

```
public boolean endOther(String a, String b) {
  char[] ac = a.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
  char[] bc = b.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
  int length = Math.min(ac.length, bc.length);
  for (int i = 1; i <= length; ++i) {
      if (ac[ac.length - i] != bc[bc.length - i]) {
        return false;
      }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Alternatively, you can just trim the longest string to the length of the shortest string and to a straight-up comparison.

```
public boolean endOther(String a, String b) {
  return a.length() < b.length()
     ? endOther(b, a)
     : a.substring(a.length() - b.length()).equalsIgnoreCase(b);
}
```

Comment: While the former method does work, I was trying to reduce verbosity (for the sake of learning to write code more efficiently).

The latter method is nice, though. I haven't gotten into (what looks like a) lambda operations yet, although I should probably start on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the **Java String.endsWith()** method.

For further info:

- https://www.baeldung.com/string/ends-with
- https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_endswith.asp

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35560735)

Comment: You are right @kamentk, thanks for the advice, I’m new here :)